# How do I escape square brackets in mysql REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have video embed code stored in a database table. We use multiple video sources, including YouTube, Viddler, and locally-stored flash files. I need to find all the records with flash files. The body field for a flash record looks like this:

```
[swf file="/sites/default/files/lecture-video/2010_02_beier_schanzer.swf" width="702" height="560"]
```

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `node_revisions` inner join node on node_revisions.nid = node.nid where node.type = "video" and node_revisions.body REGEXP "^[swf"
```

but got the following error:

> 39 - Got error 'brackets ([ ]) not balanced' from regexp

How can I escape the bracket when it's the first character I'm looking for?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use two backslashes.

```
regexp '^\\[swf'
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why it didn't occur to me to try double backslash.

Comment: For anyone wondering why you need two slashes to escape something instead of one, see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13414791/1741346).