# Why I need to double-escape (use 4 \) to find a backslash ( \ ) in pure SQL?

Tags: mysql, select, escaping, sql-like, backslash

I do not understand this MySQL behaviour : if I want to display a\b, I can just select `"a\\b"` which work without problem :

```
mysql> select "a\\b";
+-----+
| a\b |
+-----+
| a\b |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

But if I wnat to search a string containing a \ in a table using LIKE, I need to double-escape my "\". Why ?

Here is an example.

We prepare a small table.

```
create table test ( test varchar(255) );
insert into test values ( "a\\b" ) , ( "a\\b\\c" ) , ( "abcd" );

mysql> select * from test;
+-------+
| test  |
+-------+
| a\b   |
| a\b\c |
| abcd  |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

We try to get entries beginning by "a\b" ...

```
mysql> select * from test where test LIKE "a\\b%";
+------+
| test |
+------+
| abcd |
+------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Why `\\` is just ignored there? Why I need to double-escape basckslash to get my expected result?

```
mysql> select * from test where test LIKE "a\\\\b%";
+-------+
| test  |
+-------+
| a\b   |
| a\b\c |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You escape first for the string syntax, then for `LIKE` syntax.

In `LIKE` characters `%` and `_` have special meaning, so if you want to search for literal `%`, you need to use `\%`, and if you want to search for literal `\%` you need to escape the backslash as in `\\%`.

In string syntax `"` obviously has special meaning, so if you want to include quote in the string you need to escape it as `\"`, and to include literal `\"` in the string you have to escape the backslash as in `\\"`.

So in both syntaxes you have to escape `\`.

---

If you don't want to use `\` to escape the LIKE pattern , you can use ESCAPE keyword. For example:

```
...  where test LIKE "a\\b%" ESCAPE '|';
```

This way, you'll need to write `|%`, `|_` or `||` to escape these special chars.

Comment: I was thinking of such a behaviour, but that's quite not natural... There is too much levels of parsing. Just imagine if I need to put such a request in PHP, I need to escape 4 times my back slash (so use `\\\\\\\\`) because PHP has its own interpreter too.

Comment: Yes, indeed. In PHP string you'd need to escape once more. You can think of it as putting data in a box. And if you wanted to search for it with a regular expression in a PHP string, even more escaping! :)

Comment: Let me remeber not to search for several `\\` in a LIKE :p

Answer (score 8):

See [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

The `like` operator compares against a pattern, which might include `%` and `_`. To escape these, you must use `\`. So backslash is a special character, too.

When you enter the pattern string `"a\\\\b"` it is interpreted by Mysql and then again by the like operator, wich gives `"a\\b"` and then `"a\b"`.