# Selecting records with single quotes escaped by double backslashes only

Tags: mysql, sql

We have some records in this table in production environment where a particular field called  compiledlimitation contains values where single quotes are escaped by multiple backslashes.

E.g.  `Test\\'s`

We tried selecting only such records, but a query like the following returns those records which have single backslash (proper records) in addition to those which have double backslashes -

```
select * from tablename where compiledlimitation like "%\\'%"
```

The above query returns both these rows -

```
Test\\'s

Test\'s
```

How can I modify the query to fetch only rows with double backslashes.

The field compiledlimitation is a text field.

**Update**

Problem not solved yet. Both of these queries return both the records -

```
select * from tablename where compiledlimitation like "%\\\\\'%" 
select * from tablename where compiledlimitation like "%\\\'%"
```

Comment: Would that not be `\\\\\'`? [slash to escape next slash][slash] [slash to escape next slash][slash]  [slash to escape single quote][single quote]

Comment: Yes, this looks correct but I am still getting both the records. It looks strange

Comment: Issue resolved, but not sure exactly how, putting 4 backslashes for every backslash, i.e. 4+4+1=9, i.e. `where  compiledlimitation like "%\\\\\\\\\'%"` works. Found from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414791/why-i-need-to-double-escape-use-4-to-find-a-backslash-in-pure-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column RLIKE '[\\]{2}';
```

or something like that

Comment: This looks like a good one to mark as the answer, much cleaner looking than escaping each slash twice (per the SO question you linked to in your comment).

Comment: Yeah, and then I hit 3k. Whoopee! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To escape two slashes, you should just need to use four in your LIKE:

```
LIKE "%\\\\%"
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

**Table 9.1. Special Character Escape Sequences**

...
\\ => A backslash (“\”) character.
...

Comment: This looks correct but I am still getting both the records. It looks strange

Comment: It might be three like another answer. I don't have mySQL currently and I'm trying to test with sqlfiddle, but that site is having issues...

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character, so to consider 2  `\` you need to escape it with an additional `\`

```
select * from tablename where compiledlimitation like "%\\\'%"
```