# MySql Escaped \ and ' in a Like statement don't work

Tags: mysql, escaping

I want to do a simple `SELECT`and `LIKE` statements in MySql 5.5.30.
The data i'm looking for is a text presented like this in the database : `Test d\'un article`.

I searched how to escape `\'` and found that i must escape each character. I do the following:

```
SELECT
    description
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    description
LIKE
    '%\\\'%'
```

This query works just fine and returns the data i want. But if I look for the entire text like this :

```
LIKE
    'Test d\\\'un article'
```

The query returns no result. I found out that the problem is from the `d` before the backslashes, as the following query works too

```
LIKE
    '%\\\'un article'
```

and this one don't

```
LIKE
    '%d\\\'%'
```

I couldn't find any similar problem elsewhere and hope you can help me with this.

PS. : The table charset is `latin1_swedich_ci` and the engine is `MyISAM`

Comment: A single quote is "escaped" in SQL using two single quotes: `'Test d''un article'`

Comment: I didn't knew that we could double the single quote do escape it. Hovever, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Every framework that connects to a database provides functions to escape input. Use these functions instead of escaping it yourself, you spare yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbf4a8/1

Comment: @Ardgevald Why do you have this backslash in your database? I think it would be better to have `Test d'un article`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'll strongly consider that, thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The problem was from the \ that is in the database

Comment: @VMai I agree with you, but i'm not directly in charge of the database. I'll discuss about it nevertheless

Comment: @Ardgevald I understand your position, but I fear there could be a systematic error that creates this unwanted backslash. Is it a single occurrence?

Comment: @VMai No, it occurs in different records and tables. But searching records by text fields that accepts such characters is a thing we don't do often (fortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in `LIKE`, you've to double escape the backslashes. So following query will work

```
SELECT
    description
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    description
LIKE
    '%d\\\\\'un article%'
```

in `'%d\\\\\'un article%'`, first `\\\\` is double escaping of `\`, and `\'` is escaping of `'`

related SO question:
[Why I need to double-escape (use 4 \) to find a backslash ( \ ) in pure SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414791/why-i-need-to-double-escape-use-4-to-find-a-backslash-in-pure-sql)

Comment: This worked fine, but i don't quite understand why we should double escape the backslash.

Comment: None of those backslashes are needed when using standard SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbf4a8/2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OP has `\'` in db instead of `''`

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that the backslash was actually stored in the database. I somehow assumed this was part of the search string.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name me too at first :D