# How to properly escape a regular expression in Active Record where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am using `Active Record` `v4.2.1` to query a `mySQL` database using a regular expression. I would like to create the following SQL:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (email REGEXP '[@\.]gmail\.com')
```

However, I cannot seem to find the correct way to create the SQL using Active Record.

---

```
User.where("email REGEXP ?", "[@.]gmail.com").to_sql
```

*yields*

```
"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (email REGEXP '[@.]gmail.com')"
```

---

```
User.where("email REGEXP ?", "[@\.]gmail\.com").to_sql
```

*yields*

```
"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (email REGEXP '[@.]gmail.com')"
```

---

```
User.where("email REGEXP ?", "[@\\.]gmail\\.com").to_sql
```

*yields*

```
"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (email REGEXP '[@\\\\.]gmail\\\\.com')"
```

---

How do I get Active Record to properly escape the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escaping just looks wrong in the console when using `to_sql`, your last example actually sends this to MySQL:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (email REGEXP '[@\\.]gmail\\.com')
```

You can confirm this by running the actual query in the console and checking the log file.

Comment: Gotcha. This seems a good explanation of why the `\\\` is good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13415109/648494